# WPF Inlines.add: prevent linebreak

Tags: wpf, xaml

I work in WPF project and I'm new in this area.
I need to add link programatically.
Before and after the link I want to add some words.
After the words before link I put linebreak.
But the words after the link need to not have line break but continue in the **same row**.
But I got linebreak after each element that I add by 'inlines.add'.

Any solution?

Here is my code:

```
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();

        tb.Inlines.Add("this is my prefix &#x0a;");
        Hyperlink h = new Hyperlink();
        h.NavigateUri = new System.Uri(helpLinkURL);
        h.Inlines.Add("here is link text");
        h.RequestNavigate += Hyperlink_RequestNavigate;
        tb.Inlines.Add(h);
        tb.Inlines.Add("this is my suffix");
        helpLinkPlaceHolder.Inlines.Add(tb);
```

**I get:**

> this is my prefix
>
> here is link text
>
> this is my suffix

**And this is what I want to get:**

> this is my prefix
>
> here is link text this is my suffix

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.run?view=netframework-4.8) instead of TextBlock. It has propierties and functions that allows you to do this.

Comment: This remove the link from the tb inline.

Comment: Sorry didn't noticed.
After some research many people suggest to use [Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.run?view=netframework-4.8) instead of TextBlock.

Comment: can you change your answer, add this idea with working code? I don't understand what should I do. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**This way you can do it in code behind:**

```
var hyperlink = new Hyperlink(new Run("here is link text"))
{
    NavigateUri = new Uri("https://google.com")
};
hyperlink.RequestNavigate += Hyperlink_RequestNavigate;

var textblock = new TextBlock
{
    Inlines =
    {
        new Run("this is my prefix"),
        new LineBreak(),
        hyperlink,
        new Run(" this is my suffix")
    }
};
placeholderContentControl.Content = textblock;
```

placeholderContentControl is of type `<ContentControl>`

---

**How to do it in XAML:**

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0">
        this is my prefix
        <LineBreak />
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="https://google.com" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
            here is link text
        </Hyperlink>
        this is my suffix
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

**both result in the requested result: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcqy6.png)**